# How to embed a colon in the fragment part of URL without it being encoded?

Tags: http, uri, fragment-identifier, uribuilder

I am trying to construct the below URL:

```
https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/home?region=us-east-1#cluster-details:j-1IGU6572KT6LB
```

I am not sure how to include the `:j-1IGU6572KT6LB`. When I include :`, it gets encoded. Trying to see if that can be avoided.

This is what I have:

```
    UriBuilder
    .fromPath("console.aws.amazon.com")
    .path("elasticmapreduce")
    .path("home")
    .queryParam("region","us-east-1")
    .fragment("cluster-details")
    .port(-1)
    .scheme("https")
```

Comment: Seems to be a bug in UriBuider. Where does this class come from?

Comment: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder; looks like its comes from     <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: have to just convert to string and append it i guess.

Answer (score 0):

If the ":" in fragments is encoded that appears to me to be a bug (see RFC 3986, Section 3.5 and 3.3). I recommend to open a bug report.

OTOH, if a recipient fails to handle the percent-encoded colon, that's a bug as well.